# Rose::DB::Object::Manager and HTML Template

Tags: perl, rose-db-object, perl-html-template

I am using `Rose::DB::Object::Manager` (get/iterate methods) to source data from a database and `HTML::Template` for reporting.

The HTML report requires a `TMPL_LOOP` to display entries in a database.

My question is how do I create an array reference with the get/iterate methods of RDBOM and pass it to `HTML::Template`. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[Rose::DB::Object::Manager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Manager.pm)'s get/iterate methods will give you objects, but [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Template/) wants plain Perl data structures and values.  To bridge the gap, use one or more of the methods in the [Rose::DB::Object::Helpers](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Helpers.pm) module.  The [as_tree](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Helpers.pm#as_tree_%5BPARAMS%5D) or [column_value_pairs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Helpers.pm#column_value_pairs) methods are probably your best bets.